# Не завершается метод в RxJava2

Tags: kotlin, rxjava

`itemDao.getAllItems()` возвращает `Flowable<MutableList<ItemEntity>>`

`itemDao.getAllDetailsItem()` возвращает `Flowable<MutableList<DetailEntity>>`

Мне сначала нужно получить список **Items** и затем через следующий запрос в БД получить для этих элементов список **Detail**. Так как я использую сразу два объекта **Item** и **ItemEntity**, то использую свой клаcc **Mapper**, где метод `mapDetailItem` возвращает pojo класс **Item**.

Данный метод работает, но процесс не завершается и метод `loadLocalItem()` не возвращает `Flowable<MutableList<Item>>`

```
  override fun loadLocalItem(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> {
        return itemDao.getAllItems()
                .flatMap {
                    Flowable.fromIterable(it).flatMap { item ->
                        itemDao.getAllDetailsItem(item.idItem)
                                .map { details ->
                                    mapper.mapDetailItem(item, details)
                                }
                    }.toList().toFlowable()
                }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `.toList()` ждет пока "закончится поток", будет вызван `onComplete()`.

Что бы решить проблему нужно что бы `itemDao.getAllDetailsItem()` возвращал `Single<MutableList<DetailEntity>>`. Тогда ваш код будет:

```
  override fun loadLocalItem(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> {
    return itemDao.getAllItems()
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.fromIterable(it).concatMapSingle { item ->
                    itemDao.getAllDetailsItem(item.idItem)
                            .map { details ->
                                mapper.mapDetailItem(item, details)
                            }
                }.toList().toFlowable()
            }
}
```

Если же это не возможно, тогда можно попробовать так:

```
  override fun loadLocalItem(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> =
     itemDao.getAllItems()
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                    .concatMapSingle { item ->
                        itemDao.getAllDetailsItem(item.idItem)
                            .map { details ->
                                mapper.mapDetailItem(item, details)
                            }
                            .take(1)
                            .singleOrError()
                    }.toList().toFlowable()
            }
```

Comment: concatMapSingle у меня не резолвится, но получилось решить проблему поменяв Flowable на Single
```override fun loadLocalItem(): Flowable<MutableList<Item>> {
        return itemDao.getAllItems()
                .flatMap {
                    Flowable.fromIterable(it).flatMap { item ->
                        itemDao.getAllDetailsItem(item.idItem)
                                .map { details ->
                                    mapper.mapDetailItem(item, details)
                                }.toFlowable()
                    }.toList().toFlowable()
                }
  }```